# Saving Starting / Ending points of connecting line in attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, attribute-joins, connection

I have 3 layers ( 1 line and 2 points) as shown in image. The layer id,s are mixture of integers and text such as `cable4389175`, `node1` , `service_point5316`. I connect the two point layers (node and service_point) with line by using the IDs. I got the connections but the attribute table is not showing the the data of `starting`(fromNode) and `ending points` (toNode) of connecting line. For instance, `node1` is connected with `service_point53168` by forming a line `(cable4389175)`.

I have also attached a demo plot to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

- Is there a plugin or solution that will connect the points with line and also save the starting and ending points in the attribute table?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unclear whether you already have got the red line layer, or are creating it. If second option, how did you create it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a `virtual layer`.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. You would have to change the layer name and field name(s) to suit your needs.

The output is a dynamic layer, which you can then export (Shapefile or else).

```sql
SELECT c.*, n.id as fromNode, s.id as toNode
FROM cableLayer c
  LEFT JOIN nodeLayer n ON ST_INTERSECTS(ST_STARTPOINT(c.geometry),n.geometry)
  LEFT JOIN serviceLayer s ON ST_INTERSECTS(ST_ENDPOINT(c.geometry),s.geometry)
```

If you want to get this information only for cables linking a node to a service (no node-node cables), replace the `LEFT JOIN` by regular `JOIN`

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks!  I'm puzzled, however, about the use of the asterisk in the first line.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @StuSmith `c.*` means "all fields from table alias c", which in turns point to the layer `cableLayer`

Comment: Got it.  Also, I suspect that your approach requires that each line in the cable layer was correctly digitized in a from-to "downstream" sequence.  Correct?

Comment: @StuSmith yes. If not then 4 joins would be required, with a `coalesce()` on both end points to keep the not-null one

Comment: @JGH.  I have 6 points in one layer as shown in the first image. I am trying to:
(1) connect points with lines.
(2) Save data of line connections (From_point and To_point) in the seperate layer.        
  I tried to show manually here https://i.stack.imgur.com/25HKy.png