# Connecting points with lines and saving starting and ending points in new layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, points-to-line, connection, geometry-generator

I have 3 points in one layer as shown in the first image. I am trying to connect a building points with junction point by 2 lines. For demo, I have manually drawn a lines in image 2. Here, I am trying to achieve two things:

- Connect points (buildings) with Junction by lines.
- Save the data of `start point` and `end point` of connecting lines in seperate  table (layer) as shown in image 2 (rightside).

Overall, there will be `3 features in points table` and `2 features in line table`.

**What I have tried and search?**

1. I have tried `points to path` using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / points to path`. It only connect one building with junction point with no attributes (startpoint,endpoint) saved in the table.
2. I have also searched for the exisiting answers [1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306190/generating-start-and-end-points-for-linestrings/306234#306234), [2](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317461/connect-points-with-lines-qgis), [3](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247008/creating-a-line-from-two-points-in-qgis), [4](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315344/make-lines-from-points-in-geometry-generator?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I couldn,t able to solve the problem.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAp3O.png]

Comment: I don't understand the question, but maybe a virtual layer can help: SELECT make_line(a.geometry, b.geometry) geometry, 
a.id objectid, a.mrid as 'start_point', b.mrid as 'end_point', a.Class FROM newpoints_2021 a, newpoints_2021 b WHERE b.id='36' AND a.class IN ('building')

Comment: Hi @CyrilMikhalchenko. The question is to connect the points with lines and then save the start and end data of connecting line in seperate layers as shown in image 2 (rightside).

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko. The important part is to save the data of start and end points in the new layer.

Comment: Did you try to run the query I suggested with the virtual layer and then save the result? Does it meet your expectations?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` to create the lines you want:

```
if ( 
    "Class" = 'building' ,
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        geometry (
            get_feature (
                'points', 
                'Class', 
                'junction'
            )
        )
    ),
    NULL
)
```

[image]

If you want to have start- and end points as actual geometries/separate layers, you can just use `Menu vector / Geometry tools / Extract vertices` and set the lines created before as input.

To visualize start- and endpoint of this line (without creating actual geometries/new layer), add a new `symbol layer / Geometry generator / geometry type: point` and add the following expression (see screenshot below).

```
collect_geometries (
    end_point ( $geometry ), 
    start_point ( $geometry )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @babel. I can,t able to create line. Can you please share which sample files are you  using? My shape file is available here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nwpbnb61riezr5v/AAC3vGwkn-YZDna0DwnbXNJOa?dl=0

Comment: You must adapt the names of the layer and the fields to your use case: you have `Junction` with uppercase, the name of your layer is `'newpoints_2021'` instead of `'points'` etc. With the data/names you provided, I was able to create the line using: `if ( 
    "Class" = 'building' ,
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        geometry (
            get_feature (
                'newpoints_2021', 
                'Class', 
                'Junction'
            )
        )
    ),
    NULL
)`

Comment: If you use geometry generator on a symbol layer, instead of the layer name you can use the variable `@layer`. However, when using `Geometry by expression`, unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: Thank you. I able to get the connecting lines but the output layer (Modified geometry) is similar to input points as shown here https://ibb.co/dmS87pC . It does not save the start and end points as shown in the image 2 of question.

Comment: For intance, building 1 is connected with junction by line. The  output layer should save the connected points by mrids. lets say the line is connected `FROM` building `mrid (d2127ed8-de59-427a-a22f-ac7765637b9f)`  `TO` Junction `mrid (4c67ad24-7bcb-4161-a410-23196419aab4)`. The information of FROM and TO should be saved in the output file with mrid. This is what I have also tried to show manually in image 2 (rightside) in question.

Comment: Sorry, the image you linked is not accessible: "ImgBB error: Internal Server Error". You can paste the image as follows: edit your answer, paste the image there, then copy the link before saving the answer, discard the answer and insert the link to the image in the comment.

Comment: How about now? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDman.png

Comment: Yes, the picture can be seen. The solution using geometry generator is for visualization puroposes only, it does not create actual points. If you want to have start- and end points as actual geometries/separate layers, you can just use `Menu vector / Geometry tools / Extract vertices` and set the lines (Modified_geometry) as input.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Hope it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesnt work as Extract vertices only outputs zero values in attribute table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjwaY.png

Comment: Just create a new field with field calculator and `$x` to create x-coordinate and `$y` to create y-coordinate: that's what you want to get, the coordiantes of the points, right?

Comment: I have already lat, lon coordinates. I am trying to get the data of START POINT and ENDPOINT of line which connect  points.

Comment: What kind of data do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: Start and End point of connect line. Something similar here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382196/saving-starting-ending-points-of-connecting-line-in-attribute-table?noredirect=1#comment625165_382196

Comment: Like FROM Node - TO Node like here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382196/saving-starting-ending-points-of-connecting-line-in-attribute-table?noredirect=1#comment625165_382196

Comment: OK, I see: you want to get the attributes from building and junction to your start- and endpoints. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Join attributes by position`. As `Base Layer`, select the start/endpoints, as `Join Layer` select the original points (building/junction). Check the box `intersect` and choose `Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)`, than run the tool, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCO4.png

Comment: But in fact: why you want to create the start- and end point of the line? You already have these points, they are the building and junction points? So in fact you create duplicates, right? You really want that?

Comment: For better understandating, I have tried to show with a demo in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgofg.png . For instance, if I have only points layer then how can I connect nodes with lines and save START and END points in seperate layer. In the demo, a single node (cubicle146354)  is connecting 5 other nodes ( service points) along with a substattion site.What I am trying to achieve here is : `connect point with lines` and save the `Startpoint (FromNode)` to `Endpoint (ToNode)` data of every line  in new layer.

Comment: My goal is to: `(1) connect node (cubicle146354) to other 5 nodes(service points),  (2) Connect substation_site (node) with  node (cubicle146354) with lines` . (3) Save the `Startpoint (FromNode)` and `Endpoint (ToNode)` data of connecting line in new layer as shown in rightsight table of image